# Loading an object across multiple files

Tags: python

I'm making a game in Python, and I have an object to store all of the user's preferences in, referred to as `gameSettings`.

When running functions in a seperate file (`functions.py`) I have to create a new local `gameSettings` var in every single function in the file.

```
# functions.py

def myFunc1(x, y, gameSettings):
  if gameSettings.printX == True:
    print(x)

def myFunc2(z, gameSettings):
  if gameSettings.printZ == True:
    print(z)

def myFunc3(a, b, gameSettings):
  if gameSettings.add == True:
    print(a+b)
  elif gameSettings.subtract == True:
    print(a-b)

# (example code)
```

This also means I have to run the `gameSettings` object through almost every function I've written so far.

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this, as I doubt this is very efficient. I can't just import the `gameSettings` object at launch (as that would cause a circular import), but even if I could the object's variables can be modified by the user and my guess is that changing the `gameSettings` object in `main.py` will not change its `functions.py` counterpart.

Comment: If you are using a class, you could init gameSettings within the class' constructor and access the object from every method within this class.

Comment: Why would there be a circular import? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: *"my guess is that changing the `gameSettings` object in `main.py` will not change its `functions.py` counterpart"* -- Why do you think that? If `gameSettings` refers to the same object for both modules (which it sounds like it does), then both modules will see any changes to it.

Comment: `gameSettings` is instanciated and updated in `main.py`, so whenever I attempt to import it from main to functions it gives me a circular import error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you see this solution? Using a shared dictionary. From my experience, I'd store that settings as a .json file and load it when you start the game.

main.py

```
from func1 import Func1
from func2 import Func2

class GameSettings():
  def __init__(self, printX=False, printZ=False):
    self.settings = { 'printX': printX, 'printZ': printZ } 

settings = GameSettings(printX=True, printZ=False)
func1 = Func1(settings)

func1.myFunc1(1, 2)

print(func1.settings.settings)
settings.settings.update({'printX': False})
print(func1.settings.settings)
func1.myFunc1(1, 2)

func2 = Func2(settings)
func2.myFunc2(3)

settings.settings.update({'printZ': True})
func2.myFunc2(3)
```

func1.py

```
class Func1():
  def __init__(self, settings=None):
    self.settings = settings

  def myFunc1(self, x, y):
    if self.settings.settings['printX'] == True:
      print(x)
```

func2.py

```
class Func2():
  def __init__(self, settings=None):
    self.settings = settings
    
  def myFunc2(self, z):
    if self.settings.settings['printZ'] == True:
      print(z)
```

Here's the output of executing this code

```
bash-5.1$ python3 main.py 
1
{'printX': True, 'printZ': False}
{'printX': False, 'printZ': False}
3
```

Comment: So each function could be converted to a class, and on startup it would inherit the values for `gameSettings`? I think that might still create new local instances, though. And manually updating the individual instances could be more of a pain

Comment: Have you counted how many times the myFunc2 is called on the main? It's two. Have you seen how many prints you have on the output? It's 1. Changing the settings dictionary on main is changing the dictionary each class is using.

Comment: @neutral I have added some extra prints to show you from another perspective that it's indeed changing the local variable inside each class when you change it on your main

Comment: oh, I thought you were updating the local instances instead of the global one

Comment: In this simple example, a class to store settings might be overengineering, but you can consider more methods and other structurs inside GameSettings.

Comment: I think this might answer my question, though I would have to modify my code from using attributes of `gameSettings` to storing a dictionary of attributes within `gameSettings` (which I probably should have been doing before anyway)

Comment: Put some extra seconds of thought on design decisions early on a project can become a time saver in the future. Future you will be thanking past you. If it solved your issue, please, mark as correct :)

Comment: oh, so does calling `gameSettings` in a class (Func1) and setting it to a local variable (Func1.settings) update it along with the global instance of `gameSettings`? I assumed that it would just create a local instance that would be independent from the global one

Comment: this can be helpful https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply instantiate the game settings in its own module then import it and change the settings anywhere.

*settings.py*

```py
class GameSettings:
    pass

gameSettings = GameSettings()
```

*main.py*

```py
from settings import gameSettings

gamesettings.score = 0
```

It is important to realise that *settings.py* will only be executed once no matter how many times it is imported, and that the same object will be imported each time.